# How to load post titles for each category while loading all categories for a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type for an FAQ section on my page. I want each category to load as a section title, with the post titles loading below each category.

I am able to load the categories using the following code:

```
    <ul class="sort-by-category">
    <?
      $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent' => 0
      );
      $categories = get_categories( $args );
      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<li><a class="browse-categories" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
      }
    ?>
    </ul>

    <?
        // Our variables
        $page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

        // grab slug from url
        $category_id = get_query_var('cat');

        // define args
                $args = array( 
                            'posts_per_page' => '36',
              'paged'          =>  $page,
              'post_type'      => 'faqs',
              'cat'            =>  $category_id
         );

                // place args in query
                $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

                // our loop
                if($category_posts->have_posts()) { 
                while($category_posts->have_posts()) { 
                        $category_posts->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'browse' );
                }
        } 
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Please help! I'm not great with php

Comment: I don't see a *problem* in your question, what is happening or *not* happening that you would/n't like?

Comment: What is happening: the code spits out a list of the category titles. What is NOT happening: I also want to list the post titles and links to each post for each category, listed underneath their corresponding category